# Controller is taken from Url although no controller is requested in URL - c# .Net MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, webrequest

I'm currently working at a .NET 4.5 MVC 4 Web Application.
I have got the following Routes:

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "api/",
            defaults: new { controller = "Response", action = "ReturnAllStations" }
        );


        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ID",
            url: "api/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Response", action = "ReturnStuffA", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Now when I enter the URL `http://localhost:55302/api/` it all works fine. But when I enter an URL like this: `http://localhost:55302/api/SampleId1234` I get the following error "No type was found that matches the controller named 'Sample1234'."

Why does it try to get a controller named Sample1234 and not the defautlt one and use sample1234 as parameter?

Comment: can you change the order of rules ?

Answer (score 1):

Your default route should come last. Route config will look for the configuration from top to bottom and when it finds a match immediately returns invokes that action.

In your case always invoke the first configuration because it matches the `api/` configuration.

Comment: I changed the order but now I get the same error with the api/{id} and I get the response that the resource can't be found with only api/

Comment: with this`http://localhost:55302/api/SampleId1234` what are you trying to invoke? is it `Response` controllers `ReturnStuffA` action with SampleId1234 as `id` parameter? If thats the case you have to create ReturnStuffA action that accepts a string parameter named id.